# Чем отличается срез в Golang от среза в Python

Tags: python, golang

Познакомился со срезами в Golang. Честно говоря, не могу понять смысл сие.
Например, в Python, когда делаешь срез, он является списком (массивом)
В Golang, не могу понять зачем, сделали отдельный тип для среза, какая-то емкость

---

Подскажите, пожалуйста, зачем нужны вообще эти типы срезов, реальные примеры использования, зачем все эти емкости и прочее.

Comment: В питоне срез возвращает новый объект. В го срез, как я понял, хранит ссылку на оригинальный массив и значения индексов, т.е. если оригинальный массив поменяется, то в срезе тоже будет другое значение: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/8a7ee4c51e992174d432ce0f40d9387a32d6ee4a/src/runtime/slice.go#L13

Comment: Ну то есть это такое `view` как бы, интересно

Comment: @gil9red да, я знаю, что он хранит ссылку на массив, но непонятно, где это применимо и зачем это было сделано. Извечный вопрос: почему нельзя было сделать как в Python? :)

Comment: почему не так как в питоне? свой язык - свои правила. гошные срезы достаточно эффективны и позволяют просто избегать выхода за пределы массива. Но почему реализованы именно так? видимо потому, что один из разработчиков го был разработчиком си:)

Comment: Ну например есть большой массив, который поблочно нужно обработать. Если для каждого блока массива копировать память, то будет работать неэффективно. В python для таких случаев (для байт) есть memorymap, для прочих случаев - islice. А в go наоборот - по умолчанию память не копируется, но если нужно, то можно сделать копию.